# No debug option in VBA runtime error

Tags: vba, debugging, error-handling

I am using excel 2013. I do not get any debug option when there is a runtime error. How can I get a debug option during runtime errors?

Edit - I have realized that I have this problem only in the following instance. Normally I am getting the debug option (except for this case). What is especially painful is that it doesn't even tell me which line the error is on.

screenshot of error -

Code is as follows -

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub doit()

Dim intRowCounter As Long
Dim intColCounter As Long
Dim parentFormula As String
Dim resultantFormulas As String

For intRowCounter = 1 To 100
    For intColCounter = 1 To 200

        'This is the line giving the error
        parentFormula = Right(parentFormula, Len(parentFormula) - 1)

    Next intColCounter
Next intRowCounter

End Sub
```

Screenshot of the error  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fndsc.jpg

[image]

Comment: can you verify that the vba code is not protected?

Comment: Yes Mike, the VBA code is not protected. There is no debug button at all in runtime errors. There is simply no option of debug

Comment: Where is the error occuring? What is your setting under Tools>Options>General>Error Trapping?  Are you using an error handler in your code?

Comment: screenshot would be helpful, upload to imgur.com please :)  I have seen cases where the "debug" button is disabled (mostly in PowerPoint, which requires a registry change to enable it) but not seen this in Excel.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a simple case, for example, if you do `MsgBox 1/0` does that give you the option to Debug?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, that setting is selected as "Break on unhandled errors

Comment: @DavidZemens Please see the image here  http://imgur.com/gC32z74

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks :) I tried it on simple cases like Msgbox 1/0 and I got the debug option. Guess it is only occurring in some cases. I am getting it because of this line "parentFormula = Right(parentFormula, Len(parentFormula) - 1)" when parentFormula is blank.

Comment: Ahhh ok well it makes sense that you would get an error in that case, but I still don't think I've ever seen the error message without a debug option. THis does not appear to be the standard debug alert, but rather a MsgBox prompt as part of a custom error handler. Please post more of your code?

Comment: Please see code below (I have shortened it by removing code parts which are not giving any error). Now I realize this is happening in this particular case only. I try to replicate this without the for loops and I get the debug option.

Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub doit()

Dim intRowCounter As Long
Dim intColCounter As Long
Dim parentFormula As String
Dim resultantFormulas As String

For intRowCounter = 1 To 100
    For intColCounter = 1 To 200
    
        parentFormula = Right(parentFormula, Len(parentFormula) - 1)
        
    Next intColCounter
Next intRowCounter

End Sub

Comment: No. Please revise your question to include the code, it's impossible to read in comments.

Comment: @DavidZemens sorry, line breaks are not there. Please see the code here http://imgur.com/xBaFj3R

Comment: How is this procedure being called?

Comment: I am calling it just by pressing f5

Comment: If you close Excel completely, paste this code in to a new workbook with *no other code/modules*, does the same problem persist?  I'm running out of guesses here, as when I test in Excel 2010, the debug alert appears as expected.

Comment: Yes, the problem does not appear if I try this in any other workbook. Perhaps a workbook corruption issue?

Comment: that's what it would seem like.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this thread because I had a spreadsheet where I didn't get a debug option when a macro hit an error.  I found that if I make a module and put the same sub in the module instead of the Worksheet then I get the debug option when an error occurs.

If I leave the function in the Worksheet I can set the Options differently. If I leave it on "Break on Unhandled Errors" I only get an error message, if I make it "Break on All Errors" or "Break in Class Module" then I get the debug option when an error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA editor, `Tools->Options...` menu, `General` tab in the resulting dialog, set "`Break on All Errors`":

[image]