# Excel VBA not properly breaking on error

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2010, I have this snip of code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                                 
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Satisfaction Summary").Delete                      
On Error GoTo 0
Set Report = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("Main"))
'added this line to force an error:
I = 1 / 0
```

The goal is to delete the sheet if it exists, if not, ignore the error, then add in a sheet by that name.

When I go to *Tools|Options|General* and select *Break on All Errors*, if the sheet does NOT exist, the IDE will stop, and I cannot continue because of the error. If I change that setting to *Break on Unhandled Errors*, I get past that exactly as I would expect.

Unfortunately, if I leave it set on *Break on Unhandled Errors*, every other error I hit causes the debugger to stop execution, which is NOT what it's supposed to do. No, it doesn't pause execution and show me what line of code the error's on, allowing me to investigate the issue and possibly fix it, it terminates execution of the code. It does give me a dialog box showing the error number & description, but when I hit OK, code execution has terminated and it does NOT move me to the line of code where the error is.

Has anyone else ever experienced this and have any tips on resolving the issue?

EDITS: Added a line to code to force an immediate error. This is the dialog box that pops up when *Break on Unhandled Errors* is selected:

[image]

As you can see, there is no MsgBox call.

Comment: That should only happen if you have an error handler in place (which is doing exactly what it should do).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. This code is, at the moment, the only error handling I have in place. I would expect _Break on Unhandled Errors_ to pause execution on any and every other line of code that is outside the two `On Error` lines above, but it doesn't.

Comment: There was a similar question a few days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371485/no-debug-option-in-vba-runtime-error).  If you close Excel entirely, and put this code in a new workbook, does the same problem persist?  The IDE simply shouldn't break without allowing you to debug, and the message box with the error you're describing (like the other Q) appears to be a `MsgBox` prompt, rather than the actual error alert...

Comment: @DavidZemens, see the edits I made, this is not the result of a `MsgBox` call.

Comment: **If you close Excel entirely, and put this code in a new workbook, does the same problem persist?** In the other, similar question, the problem was apparently resolved by moving code to a new workbook; possibly corrupted file somehow.

Comment: **Yes**. I closed Excel, opened it fresh, pasted only the code above (with enough 'wrapper' to make it a legitimate `Sub`) and executed. I get the exact same pop up with `OK` and `Help` buttons, but no `Debug`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`.  How about checking if the sheet exists, and deleting if necessary?

```
Declare SheetExists as Boolean

SheetExists = False

For SheetCounter = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(SheetCounter).Name = "Satisfaction Summary" Then
        SheetExists = True
    End If
Next i

If SheetExists Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Satisfaction Summary").Delete
End If

'copied from code you provided
Set Report = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("Main"))
```

Comment: This avoids the error but doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: While this doesn't actually answer the question, I'm giving an up vote because it's what I ended up using to get around the issue. Based on the general lack of feedback about this, either I'm the only one with this issue, or it's a MS bug...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out instead. Same Idea, slightly different appraoch.

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next

    'Attempts to set object to worksheet you wish to delete

    Set wsSheet = Sheets("Satisfaction Summary")

    On Error GoTo 0

    'if wsSheet was successfully set to an existing sheet

    If Not wsSheet Is Nothing Then

        wsSheet.Delete

    End If
```

Comment: This avoids the error but doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I didn't test your method, but I suspect that the `Set` line would end up giving me the same issues that my initial code has.