# VBA Copy 2 Columns based on value of 1 From One Workbook to Another

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to copy account numbers and instances of a transaction from 2 columns (Columns "C" and "D", beginning at row 13) in a selected workbook to my workbook, but only if the value in Column D is greater than 1. Also, the last row in the column is labeled "Grand Total", so obviously I want to not included that row.

So far, this is what I have:

```
Private Sub CmdGetData_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim NewFile As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet


NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files (*.xlsx*, *.xlsx*")

If NewFile <> False Then
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
End If

Set ws = Worksheets("Main")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("IVR Late Fee Clean Up")

        lastrow1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 13 To lastrow2
            lastrow2 = wb2.ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            If wb2.ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = "Grand Total" Then GoTo Skip
            If wb2.ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = "2" Then
                wb.ws.Range("B" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = wb2.ws2.Range("C" & i)
                wb.ws.Range("C" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = wb2.ws2.Range("D" & i)
            End If
        Next i
Skip:

End Sub
```

The problem I am getting is "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".

Please help!

Comment: didn't read your code in full, but you are defining `lastrow2` _after_ calling it. Try transferring that line below `lastrow1`.

Comment: @CMArg: Moved the `lastrow2 =` line, still same error.

Comment: Specifying the error is much better than "it doesn't work", but saying in which line it happens would help everyone trying to solve the issue even more.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk: The error is specified at the end of the original question, "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". There is no line referenced to indicate where the error is occurring.

Comment: When you hit debug button after error message, the line with error is highlighted in VBA editor.

Comment: No option for that. Debug doesn't come up. And if I try to step into it, I get the error as soon as the source file opens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371485/no-debug-option-in-vba-runtime-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**
`If wb2.ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = "Grand Total" Then GoTo Skip`

needs to be:

```
If ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = "Grand Total" Then GoTo Skip
```

**2.** Also,

```
wb.ws.Range("B" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = wb2.ws2.Range("C" & i)
```

needs to be:

```
ws.Range("B" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = ws2.Range("C" & i)
```

etc...

**3.** And, one last thing, you have a `For` loop:

```
For i = 13 To lastrow2
```

**But**, you never set a value for `lastrow2` up to this point, only at the following line you have:

```
lastrow2 = wb2.ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

So you need to move that up 2 lines of code.

---

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CmdGetData_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim NewFile As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, i As Long

NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files (*.xlsx*, *.xlsx*")

If NewFile <> False Then
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)

    '====== ALL this code below needs to be inside the If NewFile <> False Then part =====

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("IVR Late Fee Clean Up")

    lastrow1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 13 To lastrow2
        If ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = "Grand Total" Then Exit For

        If ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = "2" Then
            ws.Range("B" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = ws2.Range("C" & i).Value
            ws.Range("C" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = ws2.Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was ALMOST what fixed it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. The code below worked! (Thank you @ShaiRado)

```
Private Sub CmdGetData_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim NewFile As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet


NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files (*.xlsx*, *.xlsx*")

If NewFile <> False Then
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
End If

Set ws = wb.Sheets("Main")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("IVR Late Fee Clean Up")

        lastrow1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 13 To lastrow2
            If ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = "Grand Total" Then GoTo Skip
            If ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = "2" Then
                ws.Range("B" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = ws2.Range("C" & i)
                ws.Range("C" & lastrow1 + 1).Value = ws2.Range("D" & i)
            End If
        Next i
Skip:

End Sub
```

And @Ryszard: I didn't get the debug option because I was running from the script editor, not the actual command button. My mistake.

Comment: you will still get an error if you press "Cancel", and usually on **SO**, when copying 95% of someone else's code and suggestions, you give them the credit, not copy>>paste as your own

Comment: @ShaiRado: Yes, I was still getting the error if I canceled the file selection. Corrected by adding `If TypeName(NewFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub` right after the `NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files (*.xlsx*, *.xlsx*")` line. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @JustinF In this site, people (@Shai Rado in this case) give you their time and knowledge _for free_. Please don't be rude and acknowledge that by accepting the answer instead of copy-pasting as your own.....

Comment: @CMArg thanks :) what are we looking for, just a little recognition

Comment: @CMArg - I WAS recognizing Shai. I realized where I didn't make that clear and corrected. I couldn't have gotten this done without his/her help.